# Можно ли достать актуальные строки (все) из Grid в ASP NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, grid, devexpress

Ситуация следующая. Есть (Devexpress)грид (readonly), который я вызываю с пустой моделью (или моделью с несколькими элементами), которые я беру из базы. Далее я хочу добавить элемент - ввожу его в текстбокс, через js передаю колбек вместе с значением в контроллер.
В контроллере я хочу получить текущее состояние грида, чтобы если элемент уже есть в гриде, просто делать апдейт его значений (и передать List в качестве модели в PartialView). Если же элемент новый, то добавить его к имеющемуся List и передать его в качестве модели в PartialView.

Звучит просто - достать данные из грида, изменить их, передать в качестве модели обратно в PartialView. Но, почему-то модель задается только при инициализации грида. То есть, та которую мы отправили в первый раз, она будет всегда возвращаться такой же в контроллер.

Вот так я передаю модель из грида в контроллер (такой способ предлагается в [документации](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNetMvc/DevExpress.Web.Mvc.GridSettingsBase.CallbackRouteValues) devexpress):

```
var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Abcd", Action = "AbcdAction", **gvData** = Json.Encode(Model)};
...
```

Вот так я получаю модель в контроллере:

```
List<ABC> prevData = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode<List<ABC>>(**gvData**);
... any manipulation with new List<ABC>, куда я добавляю новые строки, к примеру.
return PartialView("~/Views/Abcd/_gvAbcd.cshtml", model);
```

Проблема в том, что в gvData всегда летят только та модель, которая была указана при первой инициализации грида. То есть, если модель пустая, значит всегда будет возвращаться Null, если были значения возвращаются всегда эти же значения.

Что я делаю не так? Как обновить возвращаемую модель?